# Como colocar dois avisos padrão divergentes relativos ao preenchimento obrigatório no popover de um campo de pesquisa bootstrap que tem dois buttons?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Ou seja, cada botão deve fazer accionar uma mensagem diferente. Eu tenho esse campo que possui dois botões e preciso que cada um deles apresente uma mensagem de aviso diferente em caso de não preenchimento. Mas a ideia não é o preenchimento do formulário e usar o botão nº 1.

A ideia é a seguinte: O 1º botão não actua através do campo do formulário, ele serve para abrir um modal que faz parte do auxílio ao pesquisador. E o 2º botão é que actua com o código que for inserido no campo do formulário, vai abrir uma página para jogar a campanha cujo código seja indicado no campo.

Se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço muito!

```
 <input color="red" class="tftextinput3" type="text" id="searchresultsquery" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Pesquise promoções ou indique um betcode e clique play. Boa-sorte?"  autofocus name="q" title="" required="required"/>

  <button type="submit" src="https://www.clubesorte.org/c_elements/img/logos/logo_pesquisar02.png" class="searchButton2" >
    <i id="fa-search" class="fa fa-search"></i>

          <button type="submit" src="https://www.clubesorte.org/c_elements/img/logos/logo_pesquisar02.png" class="searchButton" >
    <i id="fa-search" class="fa fa-play"></i>
```

Comment: Eu posso colocar ou alterar a mensagem de aviso com este código: oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Pesquise campanhas activas')"... inserido no imput do campo de formulário/pesquisa, mas queria era inserir uma mensagem deste tipo quando se clica nos dois botões e cada um com uma mensagem diferente.

Comment: Se o primeiro btn não eh para fazer o envio ele deve ser um botão type button, e não type submit

Comment: Olá! Obrigado pela sugestão, não tinha pensado nisso. Já alterei, e como este botão vai abrir um modal relacionado com a pesquisa não é preciso colocar aviso.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolvido!**
Afinal podemos optar por colocar dois avisos divergentes em dois botões dentro de um campo de pesquisa, ou então simplesmente anular a mensagem do "required" de um dos botões. Através da sugestão apresentada pelo **hugocsl** esta situação foi resolvida e pode ser muito útil quando precisamos de colocar dois botões dentro de um campo de pesquisa ou de um motor de busca. Serve para criar duas acções relacionadas e quando não queremos colocar botões abaixo do campo do pesquisador.

A sugestão do **hugocsl** foi alterar o 1º botão de type submit para type button.

Repare no desenho abaixo, é um pesquisador por marca-de-rede da JuveCriativa Portugal. O 1º botão abre um modal de pesquisa numa tabela e o 2º botão vai abrir uma página ou pode ser usado para outra coisa, por exemplo para abrir uma pesquisa real de um motor de busca.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]